# Call $compile on custom directive

Tags: angularjs, angular-directive

I wrote custom directive `<order></order>`. It has the following template:

```
<div class="container"><div class="info"></div></div>
```

and I have parent custom directive `<container></container>`, it renders in simple 
`<div></div>`. In its link function I try to add one  `order` in the following way:

```
var compiledOrder = $compile("<order></order>")(scope);
```

I thought that it returns the compiled html (`<div></div>`), but it returns `<order></order>`. Is this an expected behavior? Can I get rendered html of directive?
Code of 'order' directive:

```
directives.directive("order",function(){
    return{
       restrict: "A/E",
       replace: true,
       scope: {
           order: "=data"
       },
       templateUrl: "http://127.0.0.1:37328/ItemTemplates/order.html",
       link: function(scope, element,attrs){
           console.log("link phase");
       }
    }
});
```

Comment: It returns `<order></order>` because `order`'s template hasn't yet been retrieved from the URL. If you specify the template inline, then it's there synchronously. But you should ask a broader question, because you may not need to do `$compile("<order>")` to begin with

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the template is inserted inside of the 'directive element' (in this case `<order />`). So you can use jqLite (or jQuery if you included it), like so

`var directiveTemplate = compiledOrder.children()`

Comment: You're right, but id ask a little different thing. Can I get not             `<order><order>` after compiling, but 'order' html template?

Comment: If you use `replace: true` in your directive config, then yes (at least I would think). But it says in the docs that this will be deprecated in the future.

Comment: Ahh...man, its all because of loading directive template...If i use `template:<div></div>` compile returns this template immediately.

Answer (score 0):

So, after some time, I decide to try with `template:`, instead of `templateUrl:`, and found that with this approach it works as I expected - `$compile(<order></order>)(scope)` returns html from 'order' directive template.